# C# the object is not created in the class

Tags: c#, list

I have a class called population which is basically a collection of chromosomes. I need to implement a property to get the higher ranked chromosome in the population.

nevertheless, I got the error system out of range. I would like to know what I'm doing wrong. Any clue or idea will be very helpful.

The Class: `public class Population<T> : List<T>` inherence from `List<T>` which is the one I used to `Add` and creates the population class.

```
public class Population<T> : List<T>
{
    private List<Chromosome> population;
    private int count;

    public Chromosome Higher()
    {
        return population.OrderBy(chr => chr.Fitness).ToList()[population.Count - 1];
    }

    public Population(int sizePopulation)
    {
        count = sizePopulation;
        population = new List<Chromosome>(sizePopulation);
    }
 }
```

This is how the class is implemented:

```
   Population<Chromosome> pop = new Population<Chromosome>(sizePop); 

   for (int i = 0; i < sizePop; i++)
            pop.Add(new Chromosome(9, 97, 122));
```

At some point here, the chromosomes are evaluated and their Fitness properties is defined.

```
   Chromosome best = pop.Higher(); //get the error out of range.
```

I should expect a chromosome as a return but I get the

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range. Must be
>   non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name:
>   index'.

population count is 0.

Comment: The problem is with this part of the code `.ToList()[population.Count - 1]`.  As the error indicates, the population count is 0, so this will give an index of `-1` which is clearly out of range (hence the exception).

Comment: Btw your problem may be where you do `pop.Add(...)` you are adding to the generic List that `Population` inherits from and **not** `population` which is the list of chromosomes

Comment: You haven't shown us the `Add` method. If it is the one that was inherited from `List<T>`, note that you have 2 lists in play here, you have the object itself, which inherits from list, and you have the `pop` list inside the class. You added elements to the object itself, not to `pop`.

Comment: Why is Population generic? You are not using the generic parameter.

Comment: Thanks Martin, but Why? is the constructor not enough to construct the Population object?

Comment: You're both inheriting from, and composing your object of a `List`. Only do one, not the other. (Hint: composing is the better choice here!) So get rid of `: List<T>` and implement your own `Add` method which adds to the population list

Comment: @carlosdelab See Jamiec's answer below which address the problem I pointed out in my comment

Comment: Agree with @Jamiec here. have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21694054/3276027). Inheriting from `List<T>` is usually the wrong choice. In your case more confusion is added having Population both inheriting and having a List`<Chromosome>`

Answer (score 3):

You're both inheriting from `List` and composing your object of a `List`! Inheriting is probably the wrong thing here, you should be using composition.

You can also make use of `Last()` to get the final item from the list after ordering.

```
public class Population
{
    private List<Chromosome> population;

    public Population(int sizePopulation)
    {
        population = new List<Chromosome>(sizePopulation);
    }

    public void Add(Chromosome chromosome)
    {
        population.Add(chromosome);
    }

    public Chromosome Higher()
    {
        return population.OrderBy(chr => chr.Fitness).Last();
    }
 }
```

And

```
Population pop = new Population(sizePop); 
for (int i = 0; i < sizePop; i++)
        pop.Add(new Chromosome(9, 97, 122));
```

Comment: Thanks Jamiec, It means I will need to implement other propierties by hand, like Count for example or indexing with []?

Comment: @carlosdelab yes, that's pretty normal for a List-y sort of class which isnt actually a list. ie, a Population doesnt have an `is-a` relationship with a list, it has a `has-a` relationship.

Comment: Or ... you could remove the `pop` field, but my advice would be to go for composition.